# Lag through Initialization of many Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Community,
I am developing an app for my school and there is one new function i've recently added, which is making me problems. It's a function where you can add our own class schedule (don't know what to call it in englisch, because i am from germany). So in that Layout there are many Spinners, which have to be initialized... I guess that's why my app is lagging, when the viewPager creates this Fragment... Here is a snippet of my code:

```
        vf = (ViewFlipper) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vf);
        DaySpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                vf.setDisplayedChild(arg2);
                if(arg2==0) {
                    for(int i=0;i<12;i++) {
                        String monSpinnerID = "MonSpin" + i;
                        String monSubSpinnerID = "MonSubSpin" + i;
                        int monResID = getResources().getIdentifier(monSpinnerID, "id", "de.ebs_hannover.sean.elsaapp");
                        int monSubResID = getResources().getIdentifier(monSubSpinnerID, "id", "de.ebs_hannover.sean.elsaapp");
                        MonSpin[i] = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(monResID);
                        MonSubSpin[i] = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(monSubResID);
                        MonSpin[i].setAdapter(teacherAdapter);
                        MonSpin[i].setSelection(getState(monSpinnerID));
                        MonSubSpin[i].setSelection(getState(monSubSpinnerID));
                        final int j = i;
                        MonSpin[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                saveState(arg2,"MonSpin" + j);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            }
                        });
                        MonSubSpin[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                saveState(arg2,"MonSubSpin" + j);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else if (arg2==1) {
                    for(int i=0;i<12;i++) {
                        String tueSpinnerID = "TueSpin" + i;
                        String tueSubSpinnerID = "TueSubSpin" + i;
                        int tueResID = getResources().getIdentifier(tueSpinnerID, "id", "de.ebs_hannover.sean.elsaapp");
                        int tueSubResID = getResources().getIdentifier(tueSubSpinnerID, "id", "de.ebs_hannover.sean.elsaapp");
                        TueSpin[i] = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(tueResID);
                        TueSubSpin[i] = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(tueSubResID);
                        TueSpin[i].setAdapter(teacherAdapter);
                        TueSpin[i].setSelection(getState(tueSpinnerID));
                        TueSubSpin[i].setSelection(getState(tueSubSpinnerID));
                        final int j = i;
                        TueSpin[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                saveState(arg2,"TueSpin" + j);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            }
                        });
                        TueSubSpin[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                saveState(arg2,"TueSubSpin" + j);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
[...]
```

the DaySpin variable is the Spinner which contains all weekdays.
MonSpin is the Spinner-Array which contains all teacher for all 12 lessons on monday.
MonSubSpin is the Spinner-Array which contains all subjects for all 12 lessons on monday.
And i've already optimized it by only initializing those Spinners, which are shown.
For example: if DaySpin item "monday" is selected, then the layout for mondays is shown and only the Spinners for "monday" are getting initialized.
And yes i need to make an extra Spinner for every Lessons for every Weekday, because it needs to be saved and loaded after closing and reopening the app.
My idea would be to only initialize those Spinners when the fragment really is shown and not only Created. That's the same thing i did for my AsyncTask... Like in this code snipped:

```
[...]
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(check2==0) {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
                    check2=1;
                    if(check==0) {
                        check2=0;
                    } else {
                        new backgroundTeacherLoading().execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        if(check3==0) {
            check2=0;
            mRunnable.run();
            check3=1;
        }
[...]
```

check equals 1 if the fragment LessonsFragment is shown and equals 0 if anyother Fragment is shown... But i don't know how to do that same thing for my initializations...
Or maybe it is my initialization of all teachers (total=87) in the "onActivityCreated()" method which has to be done, so that the adapter initializes all teachers for the spinners? Here is a snipped:

```
[...]
        teacherCountTotal = getTeacherTotal();
        if(!getFirstRun()) {
            if(teacherCountTotal == 0) {
                resetRunned();
            } else {
                teachers = new String[teacherCountTotal+1];
                for(int i=0;i<teacherCountTotal+1;i++) {
                    teachers[i] = readFile("Teacher" + i);
                }
            }
        }
[...]
```

So does anyone of you have an idea on how to reduce the lag of my Fragment, which is next to the LessonsFragment?

Comment: when you say there is lag, do you mean when starting the activity?  you should not do all that in onCreate() as onCreate is called before the Activity is in View.. instead move it to onResume() which is always called.

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about your application? What does it need to do? I don't think initializing spinners like that in a loop is the best approach... perhaps you could simplify your layout somehow?

Comment: Well it lags when i swipe to the fragment, which is next to the LessonsFragment, because then it calls the "onActivityCreated()" method of the LessonsFragment. Thats where my code is in. And onResume() gets called, when onActivityCreated() gets also called.

Comment: @Willie Nel i've already tried to simplify it... But as i said: i need to save every teacher and every subject for every day and every lesson :/